# Boton html que comunique con java en android studio

Tags: javascript, java, html, android-studio, webview-android

Buenos días me gustaría comunicar con java un botón que se encuentra en un webView escrito en html. Lo que quiero es que al pulsarlo abra, por ejemplo, otro activity, o cualquier instancia de java.

Supongo que habrá que crear un archivo javascript que contenga el método "comunicar_con_instancia_de_java" para que al pulsar el botón html abra el método javascript, y javasscript comunique con instancia de java.
Pero no tengo ni idea. Alguna sugerencia de como hacerlo, gracias de antemano.

```html
<button type="button"onclick="comunicar_con_instancia_de_java">Presióname</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Lo siguiente es lo que se explica en Android Developers, explicado de manera resumida. Ojala te sea de ayuda.

Lo primero que debes hacer es activar JavaScript para el webview.

```
WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();
webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
```

Luego de eso debes crearo utilizar una clase que contenga un metodo con el tag para exponerlo a javascript.

```
public class WebAppInterface {
    Context mContext;

    /** Instantiate the interface and set the context */
    WebAppInterface(Context c) {
        mContext = c;
    }

    /** Show a toast from the web page */
    @JavascriptInterface
    public void showToast(String toast) {
        Toast.makeText(mContext, toast, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Ahora es necesario inyectar la clase en el webview.

```
WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
webView.addJavascriptInterface(new WebAppInterface(this), "Android");
```

Por ultimo debes desde el boton realizar la llamada a una función de javascript, y desde el javascript llamar a la función de android.

```
<input type="button" value="Say hello" onClick="showAndroidToast('Hello Android!')" />

<script type="text/javascript">
    function showAndroidToast(toast) {
        Android.showToast(toast);
    }
</script>
```

Source: https://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview#java